# Third element ends up in new line in Safari

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, safari

I have a simple Bootstrap layout:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="footer_column col-md-4">
        <div class="footer_item">
            ABOUT
        </div>
        <div class="footer_item">
            <a href="{{ route('contact') }}">Contact Us</a>
        </div>
        <div class="footer_item">
            <a href="{{ route('terms') }}">Terms & Conditions</a>
        </div>
        <div class="footer_item">
            <a href="{{ route('privacy') }}">Privacy Policy</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer_column col-md-4">
        <div class="footer_item">
            SITE RESOURCES
        </div>
        <div class="footer_item">
            <a href="{{ route('rules') }}">General Rules</a>
        </div>
        <div class="footer_item">
            <a href="{{ route('rules') . '#scoring' }}">Scoring</a>
        </div>
        <div class="footer_item">
            <a href="{{ route('rules') . '#coins' }}">Game Coins</a>
        </div>
        <div class="footer_item">
            <a class="store-show">Store</a>
        </div>
        <div class="footer_item">
            <a href="{{ route('account.choose') }}">Account Types</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer_column col-md-4">
        <div class="footer_item">
            MORE FANTASY FOOTBALL
        </div>
        <div class="footer_item">
            <div class="footer_item">
                <a href="www.example.com">Fantasy Game</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In Chrome and Firefox it looks like it's supposed to (a 3 column layout):

[image]

But in Safari the 3rd column ends up in a new line below the other. When I inspect it, it has the correct width (exactly 1/3 of the total row width) in both Chrome and Safari.

I am seeing this when I inspect the element:

```
.col-md-4 {
    flex: 0 0 33.3333333333%;
    max-width: 33.3333333333%;
}
```

When I remove the `max-width` attribute, each column spreads out to 100%. This is expected I suppose. But when I add `width: 20%` for example, the width of each column remains the same as it was!

How can I make Safari behave?

Comment: Can you please add all the code for the page as it seems okay so far but there is something else conflicting. As per current code it seems you are missing container only.

Comment: Please verify you do not have any ```border```, ```padding```, ```margin``` properties effecting the divs.

Comment: what's here ``.footer_column `` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using a container around the row then add a helper class to remove the before content.

```
 <div class="container before-fix"><!-- content --></div>

 .before-fix::before {
   content: none;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ajmeese7/k5o60dwy/5/). The problem was the flex was overriding the default width.

This is what the CSS is now:

```
.col-md-4 {
    flex: none;
    max-width: 33.3333333333%;
    width: 20%;
}
```

It successfully sets the width of the columns to 20% instead of 33.3%.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a really clean way using grid instead of bootstrap...

```
.three-columns {
     display: grid;
     grid-template: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}


<div class="three-columns">
     <div>column 1</div>
     <div>column 2</div>
     <div>column 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Be aware that the `grid-template-columns` CSS property is currently only supported by Firefox 69-70.

https://caniuse.com/#search=grid-template-columns

Comment: @Timothe: while I have no idea why caniuse couldn't find data for `grid-template-columns` the resource you linked to is CSS Subgrid (as the article is titled).

Comment: I thought that was weird too. Edits made